# how to set 2D window

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

How to set up 2d view in Directx?
Is there any similar function, to this OpenGL one?

```
gluOrtho2D( 0 , 800 , 0 , 600 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivelent call in DirectX 9 would be [D3DXMatrixOrthoRH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205349%28VS.85%29.aspx) - However, you very likely will want to use the Left handed version, if you are trying to follow other DirectX code, as DirectX 9 is often done in a left handed coordinate system (instead of RH like OpenGL).  The left handed version is [D3DXMatrixOrthoLH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205346%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: What I should change in code to make it work? As calling this function doesn't change anything for me.

Comment: @Neomex: Once you build the transform, you need to set it in the device.  I'd recommend reading this: http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/matrices.html

Comment: One more question, so I need a new matrix, for every objects? So I need to call matrices, render first object, call new matrices for second, and render second one?

Comment: @Neomex: You potentially want a new world matrix per object - the View and Projection matrices stay the same.

Comment: Ok, oh, and 0/0 coordinate is in middle of screen instead of leftup/down corner, I have to create and move camera to switch it, or there's other way?

Comment: @Neomex: That's typically due to your current View matrix.  Normally, you'd just have your LookAt matrix setup in a manner that you put the origin where you want.  You'd just need to look at a different coordinate.  If you "Look at" the origin (0,0), it will be in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204940(v=vs.85).aspx to create an orthographic projection matrix for you, however actually getting this to affect your rendering is not as simple as it is with fixed-function (version 1.x style) OpenGL programming. DirectX has no immediate mode, so you would need to have an appropriate shader set to do your rendering, create your orthographic projection matrix, and pass this to the shader (and use it in the shader code).

Comment: This is not true in DirectX 9 (specified in tags) - it does have an immediate, fixed-function pipeline option.

Comment: Okay fair enough, anyway my point is really that calling D3DXMatrixOrthoLH just returns you a projection matrix that it's up to you to know how to use properly. Whereas if you're using OpenGL IM and call gluOrtho2D it will immediately affect the current matrix stack and influence your rendering.

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204940%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

Builds a left-handed orthographic projection matrix.

`D3DXMATRIX * D3DXMatrixOrthoLH(
  __inout  D3DXMATRIX *pOut,
  __in     FLOAT w,
  __in     FLOAT h,
  __in     FLOAT zn,
  __in     FLOAT zf
);`